Can you combine 2 circuits that share a neutral?
Currently, I have a home built in the late 80s that wired the house sharing neutrals. Looking to clean up the panel from a spagetti mess left by the prior owner. I am looking to combine a few circuit breakers that share a neutral. So in other words:

2 breakers of 15A sharing a netural to be pigtailed/wago together into one breaker of 15A.

2 breakers of 20A sharing a neutral to be pigtailed/wago together into one breaker of 20A


This is the current layout. The circles are for me planning the clamps for the Emporia Vue 3.


Nothing wrong with cleaning up spaghetti and nothing wrong with combining circuits if they are underutilized and you need the panel space.  Same goes for MWBCs, sharing a neutral, if you put both hots on the same breaker you will limit the max current of both to half of what it used to be, which is fine if you didn't need all that capacity.
But you should not!. One of your MWBCs is kitchen outlets.   You have two 20A circuits so you can run say a microwave on one and a toaster on the other.   The neutral wire can handle both because it's done correctly as an MWBC.  That is not something you need to "clean up" and if you do you'll just have half the capacity.  If you run two appliances like that you will pop the circuit breaker.   This should not be a target of your cleanup.
[Thanks @Jack for reminding] When de-spaghettifying do not trim wires to length, tie-wrap them or route them tightly in corners. You want maintainable. Ideally every hot should be able to reach every breaker position and every neutral and ground should be able to reach all their possible positions.  You want to be able to see how wires are routed and easily separate, remove, move, etc each wire.  Tidy is an ingredient of maintainable.  A stunning gallery-piece is not.  Do it for the next guy (probably you), not for tik tok.
Because you have some quad-plex breakers you have to be super careful to keep MWBCs on the correct phases.  I don't like your 20A/22B combination.  Though there is nothing wrong with it, from a maintainability perspective it demands that you later notice that two 120V circuits 3 spaces apart are an MWBC.    When tidying up, try to put the red/black pair on adjacent breakers on different phases.  I like to then wrap the pair of wires in a small piece of red or yellow tape.
Another nice trick for tidying up: If you are combining three or four circuits into one, you can do it in a junction box outside the panel.  If you are doing more than one of these you can combine those. EG 3 into 1, and another 3 into 1, onto an MWBC from a nearby box, you replace 18 wires in the panel with 4.  The advantage of doing this, from a maintainability perspective, is that if all your cables come in from the top or bottom, you alleviate the crowding in that part of the panel.  Finding sets of breakers that are underutilized and all on the same size breaker can be hard.  If you want to be this aggressive you may need to  put some 20A circuits onto 15A breakers, forever.

Those are my thoughts exactly regarding combining the 2 breakers sharing a neutral into 1 breaker only. That it would mean that NOW the total sum of all of the loads that used to be spread between the two breakers, will now be on only one breaker of 15A.
Regarding the kitchen circuits sharing a neutral, I plan to leave them alone.

Also, when "cleaning up the spaghetti"  it's good practice to leave enough wire so any breaker can go anywhere in the panel.

I added to the answer thanks to @JACK's reminder and also a few other tidying tips.

The circuits that share a neutral are commonly known as multi-wire branch circuits. They can share a neutral because the two hot legs are on different phases, B & A on your chart, so the load on the neutral alternates between the two phases and will never exceed the 15 amps allowed on 14 AWG wire and a 15 amp breaker. When you tie the two hots together, now both on the same phase, you could have two 15 amp circuits trying to go through a single 14 AWG wire neutral at the same time which would be 30 amps trying to go through a 15 amp breaker.
The same logic goes to the 20 amp circuits you want to combined. 20 amp breakers with #12 AWG which is good for 20 amps.

Very few "15 amp circuits" actually carry 15 amps under any circumstances.

If you put the two hots on two different breakers on the same phase you could overload the neutral.  Putting them on the same breaker is fine depending on how the circuits are used.   If there is too much load you'll pop the breaker but you won't overload the neutral..

What is breaking my brain is that, I draw it out and did the math and I can't see where the issue would be. The only time I get anything close to 15amp is if the combined loads exceed the 15amps which would trigger the breaker. It would be just like any other breaker that supplies power to multiple rooms and get combined at the junction box, but here would be right before the breaker on a wago or pigtail. Since the max amount of amps being supplied can not exceed 15amp, shouldn't the neutral never see anything above the 15A max?
Hope I explained myself properly. Thank you @Jack

@AlfredSuarezFontanez you are exactly correct in theory.  In practice we don't know your utilization.  If it's low you can do this.  But there is no compelling reason to do it, and in the kitchen you almost certainly need the capacity.

@jay613  You are totally correct. I was thinking about the two breakers on the same phase.

@AlfredSuarezFontanez  My bad.  You are right that it could be done.

@jay613 and JACK thank you for the quick replies. I am an electrical and computer engineer, but as you all know by now a mechanical engineer or being the best mechanic in the world doesn't make you a race car driver. I am blown away by how ignorant I am about practical application in everything that I come across in life.
Thank you both for taking the time to be here, replying so quickly, helping me get my head straight and educate us.

@kreemoweet true - sometimes 15A circuits carry more than 15A... briefly.

Sharing a neutral between opposing branch circuits is call a Multi-Wire Branch Circuit by the NEC. There are specific rules:

210.4 Multiwire Branch Circuits
(A) General. Branch circuits recognized by this article shall be
permitted as multiwire circuits. A multiwire circuit shall be
permitted to be considered as multiple circuits. Except as permitted
in 300.3(B)(4), all conductors of a multiwire branch circuit shall
originate from the equipment containing the branch-circuit overcurrent
protective device or protective devices.
Informational Note No. 1: A 3-phase, 4-wire, wye-connected power
system used to supply power to nonlinear loads might necessitate that
the power system design allow for the possibility of high harmonic
currents on the neutral conductor.
Informational Note No. 2: See 300.13(B) for continuity of grounded
conductors on multiwire circuits.
(B) Disconnecting Means. Each multiwire branch circuit shall be
provided with a means that will simultaneously disconnect all
ungrounded conductors at the point where the branch circuit
originates. Informational Note: See 240.15(B) for information on the
use of single-pole circuit breakers as the disconnecting means.
(C) Line-to-Neutral Loads. Multiwire branch circuits shall supply only
line-to-neutral loads. Exception No. 1: A multiwire branch circuit
that supplies only one utilization equipment shall be permitted to
supply line-to-line loads. Exception No. 2: A multiwire branch circuit
shall be permitted to supply line-to-line loads if all ungrounded
conductors of the multiwire branch circuit are opened simultaneously
by the branch-circuit overcurrent device.
(D) Grouping. The ungrounded and grounded circuit conductors of each
multiwire branch circuit shall be grouped in accordance with
200.4(B).


Whether 2 circuits with shared neutral can be combined depends entirely on the connected loads. In general, it would not be safe to do so, as the combined loads could, under some circumstances, exceed the rated capacity of the neutral wires which theretofore only had to carry the unbalanced current.

First sentence is correct.  The rest not quite.  The load on any circuit can exceed the breaker capacity. All you have to do is plug in too much.  But then the breaker pops, it has nothing to do with neutral balance or with the history of the wiring.   And you can't generalize about circuit utilization obviously ... OP knows how each circuit is used.

This answer is wrong. Converting from a MWBC (i.e. two-pole breaker) to instead feed both hots from one pole, cannot possibly overload the neutral wire(s).

You should never have two circuits fed from different breakers sharing the same neutral.  If you have that, then it needs fixing.
It's dangerous because you could overload the neutral, as in the answer by JACK.  But it's also dangerous because if one of the breakers trips for some reason, then the neutral is still energised and carrying current from the other circuit.  This can give a nasty surprise to anyone fault-finding the circuit that has tripped.
A properly designed MWBC is OK because it's fed from a double breaker.  If one side of the breaker trips, it will turn off the other side.

This answer is wrong. Code requires only common shutoff (can be achieved with a handle tie) for MWBCs. Common trip for MWBCs is NOT a code requirement.
